# Drupal import users from one install to another install

Tags: drupal

I have 2 drupal databases, 1 current database and a backup. I'm now in the situation where I need to restore the backup. I'm looking for a way to import the new users in the current database into the backup.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with SQL, just copy the appropriate SQL insert statements from a backup of your current site (the 'user' table, and possibly the 'profile_fields' and 'profile_values' if you have profile enabled).

Alternatively, it looks like these modules could possibly work together:

http://drupal.org/project/user_import
http://drupal.org/project/profile_csv

Although I haven't actually used either....